# Modify value in the vue app main.js from child component

Tags: vuejs2

I need to update a value which is initially set in the main.js for my vue application, from a component.  I am not sure the best way (or even if this is possible)

I have tried setting the value directly form the component, but it does not appear to update.

I would be happy with just having it set properly when the app starts.  I only need this to be set once, but I want it to read the server/host info when the app starts and populate the value.

```
Vue.use(Adal, {
// This config gets passed along to Adal, so all settings available to adal can be used here.
  config: {
    // 'common' (multi-tenant gateway) or Azure AD Tenant ID
    tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    // Application ID
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    // Host URI
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080',

    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  },

  // Set this to true for authentication on startup
  requireAuthOnInitialize: false,

  // Pass a vue-router object in to add route hooks with authentication and role checking
  router
});
```

The redirectUri value I would like to be dynamic based on the URL that the user used to connect to the site.  This is part of the adal-vue library to handle AzureAD Auth for my App.

It appears that this value is only set ONCE and cannot be modified on the fly.  Is there a workaround to allow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you do in `Adal.install` function, I think you can try to declare an `option` object which is passed to `Vue.use()`, then you can change the value in `option`, as it is passed by reference, the value will be changed in `Adal`...

```
const option = {
  config: {
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080',
}
Vue.use(Adal, option);

// then change it in somewhere
option.config.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:9000'
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new at vue js.  Is there any way you could provide me a sample of what you mean.  I believe I understand the concept, but I am not sure where I would put the OPTION code so that I can change it.  is OPTION just another .js file somewhere?  If yes, is it standard .js so I can add the window.local.host value or something like that in there?  Or does that option item just go into my main.js file and I modify it on the fly from like a child component?

Comment: Yes you can put the `option` code in separate file. Wait, you mean the `redirectUri ` just need to be set to the current URL ? Then why you don't use `window.location.host` or just a base url `/`? it doesn't need to change right?

Comment: This worked perfectly.  However, the option.config.redirectUri needed to be BEFORE the use statement.  As it does not change after it is already defined.  But I set the value to what I wanted before hand it it works fine.  Thanks

Comment: But your point of just setting the value in the original format to window.location.host works as well.  Not sure why I didn't think of trying that, but that is a very simple fix.